# What is the right syntax for injecting Javascript with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, javascript-injection

My goal is to inject:

```
javascript document.getElementById("pickupZip").value = "90049";
document.getElementById("refreshStoresForZipPop").click();
```

into a website with PhantomJS. This is all of the code on my inject.js file, and I get this in the console: `SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found "document" instead`, so I know it is the wrong syntax, though I can't find a place that shows what the correct is. Here is my code for the PhantomJS file:

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/purolator-classic-air-filter-a24278/5792304-P?navigationPath=L1*14934/', function(status) {
    var success = phantom.injectJs('inject.js');
    console.log(success);
    if (status === "success") {                   
      page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
            page.render('advanceautoparts.png');
            phantom.exit();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `evaluate`.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/purolator-classic-air-filter-a24278/5792304-P?navigationPath=L1*14934/', function(status) {
    var success = phantom.injectJs('inject.js');
    console.log(success);
    if (status === "success") {                   
       page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
            page.evaluate(function(s) {

                document.getElementById("pickupZip").value = "90049";
                document.getElementById("refreshStoresForZipPop").click();

              });
            page.render('advanceautoparts.png');
            phantom.exit();
        });
    }
});
```

Reference: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

Comment: I have tried that before, the problem is that nothing inside the evaluate function runs. I tested this by putting a console.log inside, and it never gets logged, nor is there the expected change in the screenshot.

Comment: @traw1234 Have you subscribed to [onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) to be able to receive console.log() output from inside of the page?

Comment: @sudipto Also I suppose you should wait a little before making a screenshot so that the target site would have time to search for that autopart.

Comment: Consider the scope/environment of your execution. `evaluate` runs on the page and not on PhantomJS. So your `console.log` inside `evaluate` will not be visible in the PhantomJS output. The best way to check is to return something from the `evaluate` function to PhantomJS scope and and then `console.log` it.

Comment: Ok so I can now read the value of the text box (90049), though I would still like to be able to take a screenshot. Is there a phantomJS function to wait?

Comment: `setTimeout` with a callback